# swiper.updateSize()/swiper.update() not working swiperjs React

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I am looking to be able to update the size of .swiper-wrapper when there is a DOM event on the current slide. The method swiper.updateSize()/swiper.update() is firing after the DOM event but it is returning undefined. This is odd because when I console.log(swiper) (the instance of swiper) it returns the swiper object instance as expected. I have added the prop autoHeight to  so according to the documentation, the height of the .swiper-wrapper should increase/decrease depending on the height of the current slide after the swiper.updateSize()/swiper.update() method is called

Is there something I am doing wrong here?

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ParentComponent(props) {
  let [swiper, setSwiper] = useState(null)

  return(
    <Swiper 
      onSwiper={(swiper) => {setSwiper(swiper)}}
      autoHeight
    >
      <ChildComponent
          title={"title"}
          text={"text"}
          swiper={swiper}
      />
    </Swiper>
  ) 
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
    let [active, setActive] = useState(false)
    let swiper = props.swiper

    // toggle active class
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (active) {
            setActive(false)
        }
        else {
            setActive(true)
            // returns swiper instance
            console.log(swiper)
            // returns undefined
            swiper.updateSize();    
        }
    }

    return (
    <div className={"infos" + (active ? ' active' : '')}>
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            <h4>{props.title}<span></span></h4>
        </div>

        <div className="text">
            <p>{props.text}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default ChildComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

ok managed to fix this by setting a timeout and waiting until after the transition had finished (or roughly close to it). The issue seemed to be that the max-height transition hadn't finished by the time the update() method was called on swiper. I also used a different method called .updateAutoHeight() which worked

my code now looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function ParentComponent(props) {
  let [swiper, setSwiper] = useState(null)

  return(
    <Swiper 
      onSwiper={(swiper) => {setSwiper(swiper)}}
      autoHeight
    >
      <ChildComponent
          title={"title"}
          text={"text"}
          swiper={swiper}
      />
    </Swiper>
  ) 
}

function ChildComponent(props) {
    let [active, setActive] = useState(false)
    let swiper = props.swiper

    // toggle active class
    const handleClick = () => {
        if (active) {
            setActive(false)
            setTimeout(() => {
                swiper.updateAutoHeight()
            }, 200)
        }
        else {
            setActive(true)
             setTimeout(() => {
                swiper.updateAutoHeight()
            }, 250)
        }
    }

    return (
    <div className={"infos" + (active ? ' active' : '')}>
        <div onClick={handleClick}>
            <h4>{props.title}<span></span></h4>
        </div>

        <div className="text">
            <p>{props.text}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

export default ChildComponent
```

I would suggest changing the timeout ms depending on how long the transition takes to finish. The higher the height of the max-height transition, the longer it will take and therefore the more delay you will need to use on the setTimeout ms for it to be picked up by the JS

Answer (score 1):

All methods of swiper need to be called in setTimeout function